# Ubuntu: TeXlive install fails everytime

Tags: texlive

I have downloaded the `tar.gz` from tug.org, and I have followed the instructions.

But every time, after an hour of installation or so, it fails because the checksum of one of the file isn't right.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Depending on your connection, it may indeed fail. It does for me somewhat regularly too. What I usually do when it does, is to install the "basic scheme" which is much lighter and then, once the distribution is in place, go installing the larger schemes from `tlmgr`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Currently retrying with a more stable connection. Where can I learn more about this "basic sheme"?

Comment: A good resource here on the site is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/105447. When you run the installer, you can set all sorts of options, the default is the "scheme full" which installs everything, but you can choose a leaner installation at this point, and add the rest later on.